# Install nltk training data manually in python

Tags: python, installation, nltk

I have installed python and nltk toolkit and I need to install the training data. The web proxy is not allowing me to use

```
nltk.download()
```

method. I tried the suggested web proxy option given in their website

http://nltk.org/data.html  but after that also proxy is blocking me to download the packages. Can I know how to install those packages manually.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data), this is all the data:

https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data

Comment: No worries, @arturomp